# Does another comma belong somewhere in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, phrasing

In conclusion, their failure to properly house their animals and educate the human population are just two reasons why zoos are not as good as they claim to be.

I'm trying to say that their failure to properly house their animals and failure to educate the human population are two separate reasons. Should I just put failure after the "and" instead to make it more clear?

Comment: You used **are** for a singular subject **failure**. Any reason?

Comment: Um, I guess I didn't realize it was a singular subject.

Comment: Oh, so that means I should say failures instead of failure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use **failures** instead of **failure**

Comment: Why would failures be plural in context it is in? "failure to properly house their animals" is only one reason.  Maybe adding "**lack of** education .... just so failure not in there twice.